# Monitoring netowork statistics on Wi-Fi direct application in Android

Tags: android, tcp, udp, wifi-direct

I'm developing an application that relies on Wi-Fi direct in order to exchange information among some devices. I use both TCP and UDP traffic and I have not rooted devices. How can I measure the traffic?